# Swift XCode Button does not appear Round

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Just for fun, I just recreated the Apple calculator in XCode with the help of a Udemy course. And in the Udemy video the lecturer explained and demonstrated how to create a "round button". I then also reprogrammed this. Only my button is just not round! The lecturer of the Udemy course also made his finished XCode file with the calculator available for download only when I open this file the buttons are not round there either. Although my button inherits from the created "Round Button" class and the class is activated, the button is somehow just not round.
I hope you can help me.
I would of course be very happy to receive an answer!
best regards
PS: Screenshots are attached

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the app? Is it round?

Comment: Your designable button built fail. Check that message first

Comment: What is the macos tag for?

Comment: You did not called super in prepareForInterfaceBuilder as stated in Apple documentation

Comment: Also, if anything is depending on width or height, you should update it properly when the size changes (e.g. checking the size in `layoutSubviews`). That's why a subclass would be a better solution.